# Apache Nifi execute task in a for loop

Tags: apache-nifi

i'm learning nifi and i need to know if it's posible to execute a task, specifically InvokeHTTP in for loop (150 times), again, i'm a complete noob lord, greetings

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Generateflowfile-> updateattribute(set attr count=150)-> UpdateAttribute(set count=count-1)-... here make 2 relations one to call http, another -routeonattribute(count>0)- return to set count=count-1

Comment: thanks, i could do it, but now, i need to stop the entire group of processors, after the execution of thos 150 invokeHTTP, how can i do that?